# Angular how to display the result of a post request in a component

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular application I am trying to display the result of a post request in another component (i.e. confirmation page). I wanted to know what would be the best way for this. In my component the code does a post request which posts to the server as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Request } from '../../models/request.model'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppComponent } from '../../../app.component';
import { nowService } from '../../services/now.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-request',
  templateUrl: './service-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-request.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceRequestComponent implements OnInit {


  public loading = false;

  private customer_id = this.appComponent.customer_id;

  serviceForm;

  u_destination_country = [
    { value: 'Choose an option' },
    { value: 'United Kingdom', },
    { value: 'United States of America', },
    { value: 'Russia', },
    { value: 'Moscow', },
    { value: 'Africa', },
  ];

  users = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  devices = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  constructor(private service: nowService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient

  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
      customer_id: new FormControl(this.customer_id),
      si_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      u_destination_country: new FormControl(this.u_destination_country[0], Validators.required),
      u_short_description: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(80)
      ])),
      u_message_description: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.http.post("/api/inc",
      this.serviceForm.value,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      }
    ).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response
      this.router.navigate(['/inc/confirmation']);
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
    });
    if(this.serviceForm.invalid) {
      this.serviceForm.setErrors({ ...this.serviceForm.errors, 'required': true });
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

So what I want to do is display the value of the `display_value` which is something like:

```
result: Array(1)
0:
display_name: "number"
display_value: "INC001"
status: "inserted"
table: "incident"
```

Comment: You can make a service which will return the `http.post()` as `Observable`. Or by binding to `@Input` property in `HTML`. Take a look here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: What do you want to do with that data in the second component? Do you want to modify them or just display the result?

Comment: Just display the value of: `display_value: "INC001"` so example: the INC001

Comment: I have found one more way, I will upload code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Angular 7.2.0 and higher**:

You can make it by using [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) built into Angular Router. For this you have to add only two things.

**First step:**

Update `this.route.navigate(['/inc/confirmation'])` to this

`this.router.navigate(['/inc/confirmation'],{state: {response}});`

**Second step:**

In your second component you can access `state` by adding this to your code

```
const state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
this.response = state.response;
```

Then you can display it.

**For Angular 7 and lower:**

**First step:**

Update `this.route.navigate(['/inc/confirmation'])` to this

`this.router.navigate(['/inc/confirmation'],{queryParams: {value: response.result[0].display_value}});`

**Second step:**

In your second component you can access `state` by adding this to your code

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
 ...
this.value = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('value');
```

Then you can display it.

**When you don't want to use URL param:**

You can create a service with one property

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedDataService {
  public sharedData;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Then you can set sharedData before you redirect to another route.

```
constructor(private sharedService: SharedDataService){}
...
this.sharedService.sharedData = response;
this.route.navigate(['/inc/confirmation']);
```

You can get that data in your second component.

```
constructor(private sharedService: SharedDataService){}
...
this.response = this.sharedService.sharedData;
```

Comment: Doing step 1 gives this error: Argument of type '{ state: { response: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: Angular version 6

Comment: Oh, this is from version 7.2.0. I have update answers with this info.

Comment: Thanks but I need solution for version 6

Comment: In long as it does the job, no I don't mind any solution

Comment: Do you need just the `display_value` nothing more there?

Comment: Just the display_value for now ---- yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189751/discussion-between-sole-and-josef-katic).