# Passing selected user data to another page (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase

Currently, I have an admin page that displays all the user's information. I want to pass only the selected user information to another page that allows me to edit their information, right now I am able to navigate to the next page but can't seem to be able to bring the data over. How do I pass the information of the user to the next page? Below are my current codes.

```
<html>
<table>
<ng-container *ngFor="let content of user">
         <tr *ngIf="content.hasMembership">
                <td >{{content.fullname}}</td>
                <td>{{content.createdIndividualAt | date}}</td>
                <td>{{getMember(content.hasMembership)}}</td>
                <td><a (click)="navigate('userSetting')"><i class="fa fa cog"></i> Setting</a></td>
         </tr>
 </ng-container>
</table> 
</html>

<typescript>
  constructor(private individualSrv: IndividualService,
private router: Router
) {
let res = individualSrv.getAll();
res.then(result => {
  result.subscribe(_user => {
    this.user = _user;
  });
});
}
navigate(path: string) {
console.log("path", path);
this.router.navigate(["/admin/" + path], {
  queryParams: { id: 'this.user.id ' }
});
}
</typescript>
```

Comment: Try to check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083161/angular-how-to-display-the-result-of-a-post-request-in-a-component/55083412

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to store the selected user in your service, route to other page and load the user from the variable.

https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the userId in the query params to your upcoming route. To use them in ext component, you will have to access them from the queryParam map of the route of the next component.

The best place to do this will be the `ngOnInit` hook of the upcoming component.

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(id); // you should have your id here.
      });
  }
```

You can assign it to a class variable and can then use as you like.

However, remember that queryParams are shown in the route Url in browser address bar. beware of passing sensitive data this way.